# Flutter hides keyboard as it pops up

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

So I have a basic login/register form.

When the soft keyboard pops up, it is dismissed. I have no clue what's dismissing it. I dont even know what code to show at this point.

[image]

Comment: I feel like I remember having a similar issue when using a stack as an ancestor of a text field; is that the case for you? Or maybe it was in a scrolling parent--can't remember.

Comment: Did you try to wrap your widgets into a `SingleChildScrollView`?

Comment: Single child scroll view gets rid of the luxe overflow, but not flashing of the keyboard.

Comment: can you add your code?